# Web deploy from Visual Studio 2015 fails with no errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, publishing

I'm trying to publish a web project to an Azure App Service site.  The compile runs and then the publish routine immediately fails with no error messages.  The Error List window in Visual Studio 2015 is displayed, but there's nothing there.

The Output window contains the following:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've tried resetting the publish profile, via the Azure Portal.  That allowed me to publish one time.  I tried to publish again and received the same, Publish failed message in the footer bar of Visual Studio:

[image]

There are no other indications of an error or any clues as to what the problem might be.

I have several other web projects in the solution that I'm using and they all seem to be working.  I have no idea what's different about this project that it is so problematic with trying to publishing.  It's just a standard ASP.NET MVC project.

**Update:**
I've discovered that if I rebuild the project (not just build) that I can publish successfully every time.  I'm not sure what that does, as I'm usually only pushing *.js files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are some locks on the app pool on Azure that prevents publishing, try recycle the app service, download the publisher profile and publish.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue and fixed it by installing the latest SDK. Install it from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/, redownload the publishing profile and then re-try the operation.